# Display Image through Parse iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a mapview that displays an array of annotations pulled from parse. Each one has a detail view controller that displays labels connected to the annotation and I am trying to have an image displayed as well but cannot seem to figure it out. Here is my current code

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Arcade"];
    self.title = @"Detail View";
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Arcade"];
    NSString *objectId = gameScore.objectId;
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:ObjectIdentifier block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error) {
        lblTitle.text = pawpost.title;
        lblPhone.text = pawpost.phone;
        lblAddress.text = pawpost.address;
        __block UIImage *MyPicture = [[UIImage alloc]init];
        PFFile *imageFile = [gameScore objectForKey:@"image"];
        [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error){
            if (!error) {
                MyPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            }
        }];
        imgView.image = MyPicture;
    }];

}
```

It does not give me any errors when I run it but it simply doesn't display.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getDataInBackgroundWithBlock is performed asynchronously and the block which includes this line:

```
 MyPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

is probably finished after the

```
imgView.image = MyPicture;
```

Try something like:

```
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:ObjectIdentifier block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error) {
    lblTitle.text = pawpost.title;
    lblPhone.text = pawpost.phone;
    lblAddress.text = pawpost.address;
    __block UIImage *MyPicture = [[UIImage alloc]init];
    PFFile *imageFile = [gameScore objectForKey:@"image"];
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error){
        if (!error) {
            MyPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            imgView.image = MyPicture;
        }
    }];

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for loading image from parse:Use `imgView` as subclass of PFImageView which is provided by Parse to load images and assign to the imageView. In that case, you can simply assign image like below:

`PFImageView * imgView = [[PFImageView alloc] init];

imgView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"..."]; // placeholder image

imgView.file = [gameScore objectForKey:@"image"];

[imgView loadInBackground];`

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-imageview/iOS

Answer (score 0):

All the above solutions are correct, but want to add one another way to have support of Image Caching of SDWebImage or any library like that.

I have answered for a similar Question. take a look
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28761476/2225439